# Python array elements in if statement

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement

I have some array with integers, and for loop. I am trying to test if some specific elements in array is bigger or smaller that some integer. This code explain it better:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(5):
    if array[i] >= 3:
        print(sometext)
    else:
        print(othertext)
```

But i got an ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

SOLUTION: I did indent it properly. This above is just simplification(some stupid example) of my code.
 I found where the error is. It is because I initialized array with numpy as

`a = numpy.empty(5)`
and not like this:

```
a = [0 for i in range(5)]
```

Thank you everybody for your help

Comment: please properly indent your code

Comment: This link might be useful to you, possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: This might seem pedantic, but that isn't an array, that is a `list`. However, your error message seems to come from `numpy`. You should provide a [mcve], although your question is almost certainly a duplicate

Comment: This isn't an array but a list with name array

Answer (score 4):

You should iterate over the array itself:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in array:
    if item >= 3:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me with proper intendations:

```
>>> array = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in range(5):
...     if array[i] >= 3:
...             print("Yes")
...     else:
...             print("No")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the most pythoninc way of doing what you're describing.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
for element in array:
    if element >= 3:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Reference: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0):

The Error that you are getting is basically due to INDENTATION . Python strictly follows indentation , meaning that it will only execute codes written in that specific Block . Refer [Python Indentation Rule](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) for more details.
Thank You. Happy Coding Ahead.

Comment: I did indent it properly in my code, but sorry, not here in post.